# Why TensorFlow Serving doesn't leverage the configured GPU?

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I'm serving a model using TensorFlow serving. After attacking to the system to serve 10 requests per second, the status of my server is:

[image: server's status]

It shows that all CPUs are busy while my GPU is idle. I found that about 50% of my requests takes longer than 30 seconds.

**Why TensorFlow Serving doesn't leverage my GPU?**

Comment: It seems that TensorFlow Serving should compile with CUDA support. I could not find any relevant documents in tf-serving web site.